# Disable log4j and slf4j initialization output for external libraries

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

When running my application I see on the stdout the following log4j initialization infos:

```
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [OFF].
log4j: root level set to OFF
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
```

This is probably coming from external libraries using [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/) and [slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/).
I am trying to suppress these initialization infos, but even setting the root logger level to OFF does not seem to have any effect.
This is the log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It's because you have `debug="true"` in your config.

Comment: Thanks! It was very easy

Answer (score 1):

Solved setting debug to false in log4j.xml:

```
<log4j:configuration debug="false"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```